# [Apple][HLS] The adaptive bitrate metadata of a video

Tags: video, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, transcode, adaptive-bitrate

My vendor said some of my transcoded .ts videos' ABR (adaptive bitrate) metadata is marked/located differently than others.

**What I have done**

I google searched what is adaptive bitrate and know that is something the Apple introduced. But I cannot find what is a "Adaptive Bitrate Metadata" and where to find it

I have also compared the okay videos and the not-okay videos via *MediaInfo* and nothing seems to cause the failure

---

May I get some helps here? On whatever how can to refer to the 'metadata' of the files or something to test the videos if it okay for an Apple HLS

Comment: You should have a *variant* playlist, an `m3u8` file containing the stream information (it's using `EXT-X-STREAM-INF` tags). Add the contents of the file to your original question.

Comment: Hi aergistal, thanks for your reply but the playlist is not my work before the vendor want to make that themselves. They now is just said some of the 'metadata' is not same as some others and that's confuse me..

Comment: Can you post the `mediainfo` for one file which is OK and one for a file which is bad, according to your vendors?  They probably mean some encoding parameters are different.

Comment: Yeah that's what I am thinking, but they didn't indicate which is good nor bad... Still waiting for their reply

Comment: You can see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2224/_index.html in the meantime. Also make sure your streams are keyframe aligned.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the bitrate mode should be 'Constant' instead of 'Variable'